# How to set fetch mode to retrieve single result from a collection in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate with criteria.

I have a java model defined like this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questionask", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"))
public class QuestionAsk extends LobEntity implements Comparable<Object> {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "questionAsk")
    private List<Answer> answerList = new Arraylist<Answer>(0);

//getters and settes

..
}
```

If I want to retrieve answer list with the fetched data, I set;

```
criteria.setFetchMode(property,  FetchMode.JOIN); //This works .
```

But My requirement is, I want to fetch some records from the collection, when user requests. That is, When user provides following query,(In the answerList  each answer has `code` attribute)

```
answerList.code=an_123
```

I would like to retrieve the answerList with that single answer. But it does not working to me. (means, it is not fetching the answerList which I defined as lazy Loading)

I try like,
 criteria.setFetchMode(answerList,  FetchMode.JOIN); with other required `joins` and `ins`.

How can I do this with criteria? Does Hibernate support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the use case you want is supported by hibernate.

Why not invert the join you do : doing the query to get the `Answer`s you want, and then getting the `QuestionAsk` linked to it ?

You could even aggregate the result of this query in a `Map<QuestionAsk, Set<Answer>>`. This way there would be no ambiguity : `mapEntry.getKey().getAnswerList()` would return all the answers of a question, as expected, and `mapEntry.getValue()` would return the answers filtered.